# IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "char" exists so how do i go about this?

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, intellisense

the char letters[] = {value}; part is where i am getting the problem

```
 static string Cipher(string value, int offset)
  { 
char letters[] = {value};
char DifferentLetters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','u','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'};


for (int i = 0; i < DifferentLetters[i]; i++)
{
    char letter = DifferentLetters[i];

    int defaultOffset = offset;

    if(letter > 'z')
    {
        letter = (char)(letter - defaultOffset);
    }
    else if(letter < 'a')
```

Comment: What do you need that line for? Just remove it.

Comment: How do you go about ... what?

Comment: @juanchopanza how do i change that line so that the value is converted to a char

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the more basic question of why you would want to do such a thing, the equivalent to what you expect

```
char letters[] = {value};
```

to mean would be

```
char letters[value.size()+1];
memcpy(letters,value.c_str(),value.size()+1);
```

Of course, that assumes a newer version of C++ that allows run time sizing of local C arrays (I forget which version that was added in, but certainly not very early versions).  Also you need to include something like string.h to get the declaraction of memcpy.

The following **might** be a cleaner alternative, but it is further from the original meaning in ways that may cause it to be unacceptable (depending on subsequent use of letters and value):

```
char* letters = value.c_str();
```

Comment: *"I forget which version that was added in"* -- Are you from the future?

Comment: I guess you mean it wasn't added to any version of the standard and it only works as a common extension.  You might be right.  I'm obviously far from expert on what is in which version of the C++ standard.  But it works in each of the several C++ compilers I commonly use.

Comment: Yes. Correct. It is a GCC extension, (and maybe clang too). Though not in Visual-C++. If you want to ensure errors on non-standard extensions, use `-pedantic-errors`. Or `-pedantic` if you just want warnings.